# Place values to hidden field using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, hidden-field

I'm trying to place a data to a hidden field using JQuery, I want to place a text to the field
"fieldName" with custom values, but I don't know how to pass the text to the field using jQuery.

The code that I used is:

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').click(function(){
    $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150);

});
```

The field is  inside the div apply-modal.

I want to place the value "Accountant" to the hidden field after the FadeIn(150) is called. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').click(function(){
    $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150);
    $("#hidden_field_id").val('Accountant');
});
```

To put the value after the fade is executed try this:

```
$('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150, function(){
    $("#hidden_field_id").val('Accountant');
});
```

Comment: that is not AFTER the fade

Comment: It will be executed after the fade line is executed, but before the fade has finished.

Comment: Glad to be of service

Comment: if it solved your query consider accepting the answer. @mplungjan

Comment: Not my question. But my suggestion you added to your answer

Comment: oops... :D @mplungjan

Comment: Just tried it and it works, sorry took a long time to reply, I'm using yii framework for my forms. Thanks!!

Comment: Happie to help buddy :D @marchemike

Answer (score 2):

assume that your hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="account_field" id="account_field">
```

now in js

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').click(function(){
    $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150);
    $("#account_field").val("Accountant");
});
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function `val()`. documentation for [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.
Try this:

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').click(function(){
    $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150, function() {
        $('#fieldName').val('Accountant');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **.val()** for adding text

```
$('#fieldName').val('Accountant');
```

Assuming "fieldName" is an id.

Your code will be

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').click(function(){
    $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150);
    $('#fieldName').val('Accountant');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so AFTER the fadeIn is complete, use the [callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#fadeIn-duration-complete)

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').on("click",function(){
  $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150,function() {
    $("#account_field").val("Accountant");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above suggested method of using the callback function for the fadeIn or you can use setTimeout function:-

```
$('span.open-apply-modal').on("click",function(){
 $('#apply-modal, #modal-backdrop').fadeIn(150);
   setTimeout(function(){
     $("#account_field").val("Accountant");
   }, 150);
});
```